# Is this proof correct to prove the role of transformation matrix in coordinates (wrt ordered basis) of 2 vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Let there be 2 vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with corresponding ordered basis $B = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ and $C = (c_1,\ldots,c_m)$.

Let $\varphi$ be the linear mapping $\varphi:V\to W$

Then, every vector $x$ belonging to $V$ can be represented as $x = B\hat{x}$ where $\hat{x}$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ wrt $V$

and every vector $y$ belonging to $W$ can be represented as $y=C\hat{y}$ where $\hat{y}$ is the coordinate vector of $y$ wrt $W$

Now, for every basis vector $b_j$ of $V$,

$\varphi(b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{ij}c_i$

$\alpha_{ij}$ are elements of the matrix $A$

Therefore, we have $\varphi(B) = CA$

Now,
$y = C\hat{y}$

$\hat{y} = C^{-1}y$

$\hat{y} = C^{-1}\varphi(x)$

$\hat{y} = C^{-1}\varphi(B\hat{x})$

$\hat{y} = C^{-1}\varphi(B)\hat{x}$

$\hat{y} = C^{-1}CA\hat{x}$

and finally,

$\hat{y} = A\hat{x}$

In this proof, can we say that $\varphi(B\hat{x}) = \varphi(B)\hat{x}$ because $\varphi$ is a linear mapping?

Also, what is the intuition behind A? I am unable to find the intuitive connect between

$\varphi(b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{ij}c_i$

and

$\hat{y} = A\hat{x}$

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I see you're trying to format things; that's good. General tip: You can/should encase the whole equation in \$\$ rather than each individual element. For example, to get $a_i=b_i+c_i$, write \$a_i=b_i+c_i\$ rather than \$a_i\$=\$b_i\$+\$c_i\$.